# Img responsive sizes not working, srcset/sizes

Tags: html, image, src, srcset

I am not getting the right image when I am looking on an mobile device.

When I am looking on desktop on a browser in a responsive viewport i am getting the correct image.

When I alert an `screen.width` I get 360 on my phone. So there is nothing wrong with the width of my phone.

Code:

```html
 <img srcset="/media/4b/4baf66ec59753d3dfgh7fa0a0bcbca25/576x336/impressie-header.jpg 576w,
    /media/4b/4baf66ec59753d3dfgh7fa0a0bcbca25/768x348/impressie-header.jpg 768w,
    /media/4b/4baf66ec59753d3dfgh7fa0a0bcbca25/992x372/impressie-header.jpg 992w,
    /media/4b/4baf66ec59753d3dfgh7fa0a0bcbca25/1200x450/impressie-header.jpg 1200w,
    /media/4b/4baf66ec59753d3dfgh7fa0a0bcbca25/1920x720/impressie-header.jpg 1920w,
    /media/4b/4baf66ec59753d3dfgh7fa0a0bcbca25/2560x960/impressie-header.jpg 2560w" 
    
    sizes="(max-width: 576px) 100vw,
          (max-width: 768px) 100vw,
          (max-width: 992px) 100vw,
          (max-width: 1200px) 100vw,
          (max-width: 1920px) 100vw,100vw" 
          
          alt="impressie-header.jpg" 
          class="d-block w-100">
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: you have this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> in your head tag?

Comment: Not exactly, I have: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">